# Asp.net MVC 5 passing model object to controller via ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I need some help/advise on how to make this work.
I need to pass the model from the view to the controller through an ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Radera", "DeleteTraffic", new { model = Model, trafficId = traffic.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-link NoBorder NoBackGround" })
```

the method in the controller looks like this.

```
public ActionResult DeleteTraffic(CalendarModel model, int trafficId)
    {

        return View("EditDay", model);
    }
```

I have not put any code in the method yet, I've only been debugging it to get the call to work. model is null when I press the button, trafficId is however correctly set. so what have I done wrong?

Edit 1:
I've changed the code according to the suggestions here.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteTraffic", "Calendar", new {trafficId = traffic.Id})) {<input type="submit" value="Radera" class="btn btn-link NoBorder NoBackGround"/>}

[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ActionName("DeleteTraffic")]
    public ActionResult DeleteTraffic(int trafficId)
    {



        return View("EditDay", Model);
    }
```

but DeleteTraffic is never reched, instead it calls the Main Action for this page.

```
// GET: Calendar
    public ActionResult Calendar()
    {


        CalendarModel model = new CalendarModel {SelectedDate = DateTime.Today};
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("submit.SelectDate")))
            {
                model.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["selectedDate"]);
                model.TrafficDates = TrafficData.GeTrafficDatesPerMonth(model.SelectedDate);
                Model = model;
                return View("EditDay", Model);
            }

        }
        Model = model;
        return View(Model);
    }
```

should I just tuck the trafficId into a hiddenfield and use this action for everything? MVC seems so inflexible at times...

Comment: It `new { Model, trafficId = traffic.Id }` but it will not bind correctly if any properties of the model are complex objects or collections (and you could exceed the query string limit. Why do you think you need to do this - you should be just passing the `ID` property of the model, not the whole model. And a Delete should never be a GET. You should be using a form and posting the ID value(s)

Comment: I could just send the trafficId and ignore the model. the reason I did this was to go back to the edit site after the delete had been handled. the model object is essential when loading the site so that's why I passed it back and forth. I could store it in a session variable, but I don't know if there's a better way. The reason I didn't want to do a form and post is that the CalendarModel contains a lot of data that I don't want the app to keep rebuilding everytime the user presses a button

Comment: A better way is always to get it from the database again. And if it does contain a lot of data, then you will almost certainly throw an exception because of the query string limit. But as I noted, a Delete needs to be a POST, not a GET.

Comment: How would I turn the ActionLink into a post then? is there an attribute I need to put over the method in the controller?

Comment: `@using(Html.BeginForm("DeleteTraffic", "yourControllerName", new { trafficId = traffic.Id })) { <input type="submit" value="Radera" /> }` and mark the method with `[HttpPost]` (you probably also want the `AntiForgeryToken` as well)

Comment: There's one thing I can't wrap my head around, I have a bunch of TextBoxFor, DropDownListFor with properties in the model. if I do that post with only the trafficId as parameter, how would I access the values from these dropdowns and textboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, something like a "delete" should *never* be handled by GET. Deleting is atomic and should be done utilizing either the POST or DELETE (preferably) verbs. Generally, you also should not just delete something without user confirmation, so the simplest and correct way to handle this would be to have the "delete" link take the user to a view that asks them to confirm deleting the item. On this view, then, you would submit the id of the item to be deleted via a form post:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
    if (foo == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    return View(foo);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirm(int id)
{
    var foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
    if (foo == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    db.Foos.Remove(foo);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Then, for your GET action, you would add a `Delete.cshtml` file:

```
@model Namespace.To.Foo

<p>Are you sure you want to delete the foo, "@Model.Name"?</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
}
```

Alternatively (or rather progressively, as you should still have the previous method as a fallback), you could use a JavaScript confirm and AJAX to do this, if you don't want to change pages:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Radera", "DeleteTraffic", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-link NoBorder NoBackGround delete", data_id = item.Id })
```

Then:

```
<script>
    $('.delete').on('click', function () {
        var $deleteLink = $(this);
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            $.post('/url/for/delete/', { id = $deleteLink.data('id') }, function () {
                $deleteLink.closest('tr').remove();
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```